# qliksense : Embed qlik dashboard in an internal website

Tags: qliksense

Hi,

We have a Data-portal which is an internal portal that centralize every data of the company and provide a Data catalog to our users.

We ‘d like to embed Qlik dashboards in the website for users who have licences.

Do you have an advice us on how to embed Qlik Dashboards in our portal and also make sure that the SSO connection can be forwarded?

Version of qliksense is 12.44

Thanks,
Romain.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Dev Hub. You can access dev hub via qliksense or directly by going to https:///dev-hub/ There are many interesting tools.

More info about embedding here:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2019/Subsystems/Platform/Content/Sense_PlatformOverview/Integration/embed-qlik-sense.htm